# How to show message box that has title in javascript?

Tags: asp.net

How do I create a message box that has title instead of "Localhost: page says" in javascript? I know it is not possible with an alert box. In an alert box I can not change 
the title. I am using asp.net, C# and javascript. I don't know vb script. Is it possible in javascript?

Comment: the simple and easy message box have many limitations, but you can create a full custom dialog using javascript and a lot of code (or find one from the internet)

Comment: for security reasons you can't simply do that with a javascript alert. make use of jquery-ui dialog

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it doesn't have any implemented "out of the box" functions.

You can build your own function that generates div and shows it holding your message in the middle of the page or you can use one of the javascript framework extensions that implement that.

Or you can check out [jQuery UI modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), since it's very simple to use

On the other subject, vbscript is an old MS product, it's not used any more and works only on Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

check out this site http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/
you can always use jquery alerts.